# Camel File Component stops consuming files sometimes

Tags: spring-boot, unix, io, apache-camel, apache-karaf

Hi. I'm having a pretty nasty issue with the app I'm responsible for. The app was running on osgi/karaf + spring + apache camel 2.14.1. I removed osgi/karaf, upgraded spring, and moved all that to the spring boot. Camel version was upgraded to 2.24.1. And we started to see some occasional perf. issues on prod. I wasn't able to see the logs until yesterday, but what I saw there confused me a lot. The app at some point stopped processing the files for one of the routes, while the second route was working fine...

And it lasted for almost 2 hours. Yes, we have pretty high load on it but it was always like that. I just can't figure out what exactly could possibly cause that.

Few small details though... The files which this failing route is monitoring are put to the folder through the symb link. So if the monitoring folder name is /test, there is a link to it in $HOME/test(for a different user) and the other process connects through the sftp and puts files to that folder(it's not a problem with that process, I'm 100% sure that the files were on the server but this thing just didn't see them).

I to be honest have no idea where to dig. The server is pretty old, and the FS is pretty defragmented, we have also disk usage on 100%(but our admins don't think it's related + it was like that before and there were no issues). Java changed by the way from 1.6 to 1.8. I also checked the memory, it doesn't seem like there is an issue, one global GC during the 12 hours, minor collections are not that frequent. I would really appreciate any thoughts... Thank you very much!

Comment: 100% du is got to be the place to start. Good luck.

Comment: If disk usage is full, I don't think camel can process the file because camel creates a lock file with the naming pattern .<fileName> in the same directory and move the files to a different location once it is processed. So if the DU is 100% it cannot process the files properly.

Comment: Thank you! Yes, having a meeting with the admins today. I'm also thinking that the link might affect it. We'll see:)